# I not able to import pygame module in linux

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, pygame, python-import

[![this is the image for reference

> I am not able to use the init function.
>   please solve this issue.

][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmqz4.png)][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cmqz4.png)

Comment: "The init function" tells us nothing.  Please include actual details in your question.  Image links don't count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You named your script `pygame.py`, that is a very bad idea because it shadows the real `pygame` module, change the name of your script and it should work fine.

Comment: Ya i got to know it afterwards. Thanyou by the way